# Installing GCC 4.4.7 on OSX 10.10

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc

I already have gcc version 6.1.0 installed on my computer thanks to XCode:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

But I need to install gcc version 4.4.7 and I have tried doing things like brew install gcc447 and such but it always says package not found. Is there a way to install gcc 4.4.7 on OSX 10.10 and have it run as "gcc4" or a similar alias while still keeping the XCode 6.1.0 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't have recipes for every individual minor version of GCC, only for the major versions like 4.4. Conveniently, though, 4.4.7 is the most recent version of GCC 4.4, so you're fine.

Run `brew install gcc44`; the compiler will be installed as `gcc-4.4`.